# GCC Inline Assembler "memory" Clobber don't prevent from re-arrange the code in ARM

Tags: gcc, optimization, arm, inline-assembly, barrier

I read article about GCC Inline Assembler
(http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html).

In this article,  "memory" Clobber forces the compiler to store all
cached values before and reload them after executing the assembler
instructions. And it must retain the sequence.

this is the example.
The following code intends to multiply c with b, of which one or both
may be modified by an interrupt routine. Disabling interrupts before
accessing the variables and re-enable them afterwards looks like a
good idea.

This may fail. Because the optimizer may decide to do the
multiplication first and then execute both inline assembler
instructions or vice versa.  :

```
asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n\t"
    "orr r12, r12, #0xC0\n\t"
    "msr cpsr_c, r12\n\t" ::: "r12", "cc");
c *= b; /* This may fail. */
asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n"
    "bic r12, r12, #0xC0\n"
    "msr cpsr_c, r12" ::: "r12", "cc");
```

This is safe by adding "memory" Clobber .

```
asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n\t"
    "orr r12, r12, #0xC0\n\t"
    "msr cpsr_c, r12\n\t" :: : "r12", "cc", "memory");
c *= b; /* This is safe. */
asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n"
    "bic r12, r12, #0xC0\n"
    "msr cpsr_c, r12" ::: "r12", "cc", "memory");
```

But I disassemble code by objdump -d .  "memory" Clobber  don't works,
the code is to do execute both inline assembler instructions, and then
do the multiplication.

```
mrs     ip, CPSR
orr     ip, ip, #192    ; 0xc0
msr     CPSR_c, ip
mrs     ip, CPSR
bic     ip, ip, #192    ; 0xc0
msr     CPSR_c, ip
mul     r0, r1, r0
mov     pc, lr
```

Can anyone explain why"memory" Clobber don't works？

note:
source code.it may fail.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
            int a = mul(20, 10);
            printf("%d a\n", a); 
            return 0;
    };

    int mul(int b, int c)  
    {
            asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n\t"
                            "orr r12, r12, #0xC0\n\t"
                            "msr cpsr_c, r12\n\t" ::: "r12", "cc");

            c *= b; /* This may fail. */

            asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n"
                            "bic r12, r12, #0xC0\n"
                            "msr cpsr_c, r12" : :: "r12", "cc");

            return c;
    }
    ~
```

this is safe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a = mul(20, 10);
        printf("%d a\n", a); 
        return 0;
};

int mul(int b, int c)  
{
        asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n\t"
                        "orr r12, r12, #0xC0\n\t"
                        "msr cpsr_c, r12\n\t" : "=X" (b) :: "r12", "cc");
        c *= b; /* This is safe. */
        asm volatile("mrs r12, cpsr\n"
                        "bic r12, r12, #0xC0\n"
                        "msr cpsr_c, r12" :: "X" (c) : "r12", "cc");

        return c;
}
```

compile and disassemble command:

```
lumotuwe@ubuntu:~/test_nfc$ arm-linux-gcc -O2 inline_asm.c 
lumotuwe@ubuntu:~/test_nfc$ arm-linux-objdump -d a.out
```

Comment: What happens if you put a fake dependency on the inline. On the first asm block do this `"msr cpsr_c, r12\n\t" :"=m"(b): : "r12", "cc", "memory");` and then on the second one `"msr cpsr_c, r12" :"+m"(c):: "r12", "cc", "memory");` .The compiler is free to relocate the asm blocks even if they are volatile (even moving them relative to other _C_ statements) if it doesn't see dependencies.

Comment: Compiler retain the sequence of statements given in the source code If i put a fake dependency on the inline.

Comment: You put those exact dependencies that I gave (changes to both inline assembly) and the order didn't change. You sure?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal complete verifiable example. Not just a code snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If my original changes above actually worked you should find you can remove the `memory` clobber from both and tighten things up by changing `"=m"(b)` to `"+rm"(b)` and `"+m"(c)` to `"+rm"(c)` . It should have been `+` on both, my first example was slightly in error.

Comment: I tossed it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/upqQhZ) . If you change `#if 1` to `#if 0` you can go from my code to yours.

Comment: An observation in use of the `memory` clobber: If the values are in registers and not backed by memory then they won't be affected by the `memory` clobber. I noticed your `mul` does everything in registers which suggests b and c are not being stored in memory and thus won't be flushed and reloaded from memory with a `memory` clobber.

Comment: Something I missed the first time in your question You say that _b_ and _c_ can be modified by an interrupt handler. Given that the `mul` instruction in your outputted assembly is working on registers - did you forget to mark _b_ and _c_ with the volatile keyword like `volatile int b,c;` ? If they aren't marked volatile then the compiler won't know they can be modified asynchronously and will retain them in registers if the optimizer can do that.

Comment: I have seen your edit. The problem is that you say `b` and `c` can be modified by interrupts. Not sure how that is possible in this code. b and c are passed in registers so `memory` clobber won't do anything. You may get the desired result if you change mul's prototype to `int mul(volatile int b, volatile int c)` or you make a fake dependency like I suggested earlier to force the order.

Comment: With your new code and adding my original idea of ordering the instructions with fake dependencies (without the memory clobber) does seem to work: https://godbolt.org/g/mQzm1a

Comment: Thanks for your help. does it  mean that memory clobber work under variable only  in ram, not in registers ?

Comment: The `memory` clobber will only affect variables that have backing in memory. If the optimizer can inline everything it will and likely has most things in registers. If you are doing interrupts where b and c can be modified externally you should be marking them in memory as volatile (I assume they would be global variables) and passing pointer into `mul` and not pass them by value

Comment: Here's an example of your code that marks b and c as volatile (global variables that may be modified by an interrupt routine for example). We pass pointers to volatile ints to `mul` . We place the equation between the two inline assembly blocks. https://godbolt.org/g/scJsXY

Comment: In the godbolt example in my last comment you may notice that the `mul` is done outside the blocks which is fine because it loads the values from memory for both variables inside the blocks. Because the parameters are marked pointers to volatile values the optimizer is prevented from doing optimizations it may have been able to do previously.

Comment: The other option is to use your original code and turn off interrupts before you call `mul` and then turn them back on after. https://godbolt.org/g/bDQCyv

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the question, the variables `a`, `b` and `c` can not be modified by an interrupt as they are local variables and there is no pointer to them.

If a pointer to the variables is stored in a global variable which an interrupt handler could use access the variable, the `"memory"` clobber will ensure access to variables is not moved past the `asm` statement.

Either `volatile` or a `"memory"` is required, ther is no need to do both.